# How to create clustered bar chart in altair

Tags: python, altair

I am trying to plot a simple clustered bar graph of Activity1 and Activity2 for each month next to each other. I couldn't get it working. Grouped bar chart is the closest example I could find, but still doesn't meet my requirements. 
I tried by using long format with melt, but still not able to produce a clustered bar chart. 
I would really appreciate if someone could help me figure out how to create it using altair.

```
d = {'Month':[1,2,3,4,5,6], 
     'Act1':[10,20,25,32,45,50],
     'Act2':[20,35,45,55,65,75]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(d)

dfm = pd.melt(df,id_vars=['Month'], value_vars = ['Act1','Act2'], var_name='Activity',value_name='Total')

alt.Chart(dfm).mark_bar().encode(
    x='Month:O',
    y='sum(Total):Q',
    color='Activity:O',
    column='Activity:O'
)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you switch your `column` and `x` encodings, you'll get a grouped bar chart. To clean it up, you can remove the x-encoding labels as well:

```
alt.Chart(dfm).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X('Activity:O', title=None, axis=None),
    y='sum(Total):Q',
    color='Activity:O',
    column='Month:O',
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Still couple of more improvement issues on this graph, if I may  
1. How to get the month numbers at the bottom? 
2. How to make the tick marks full length instead of ending at column?
3. What factor decides whether graph should be stacked or shown side by side when it's not specified explicitly?

Comment: 1) there is currently no way to do that that I know of. 2) I'm not sure what you mean. 3) Bars are always stacked if multiple categories have the same encoding. Here, we explicitly split multiple categories among the x and column encodings, so there is no stacking.